# What do the "1.0" and "OAS3" labels mean in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

Swagger UI shows the "1.0" and "OAS3" labels next to the API title. What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: hi & welcome! `1.0` refers to (api>)"info">"version", whereas "oas3" (apparently) signals  "openapi" >= 3. [see here](https://editor.swagger.io/) (Compare with v2: Edit>Load Petstore OAS 2.0)

Comment: @xerx593 you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently ([1](https://editor.swagger.io/), [2](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/info.jsx), [3](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/plugins/oas3/helpers.jsx)):

- `1.0` refers to `info.version` of your API definition.
- `OAS3` signals, that underlying API has `open-api` (major) version 3.